Too many package installation in Expo React Native
This is my current package.json and I am installing packages using yarn. Although I only have these dependencies, it installs over 1000 packages and frequently fails to install and gives
➤ YN0001: │ Error: Couldn't allocate enough memory
    at ZipFS.getBufferAndClose ([worker eval]:1:298046)
    at ZipFS.saveAndClose ([worker eval]:1:299036)
    at convertToZipWorker ([worker eval]:1:407956)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async MessagePort.<anonymous> ([worker eval]:1:409728)

this error and also fails to install dependencies when I upload it to EAS Expo. How can I fix this error...?
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/jaldi": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@realm/react": "^0.8.0",
    "@rneui/base": "4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "expo": "~51.0.11",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "^6.4.1",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.20",
    "expo-image": "^1.12.11",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.16",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "realm": "^12.11.1",
    "validator": "^13.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.8",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.0",
    "@realm/babel-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7.20.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/supports-color": "^8.1.3",
    "@types/validator": "^13",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "supports-color": "^8.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.3.1"

I have been trying deleting some dependencies and reinstalling packages and upload to EAS but none worked. Will it be solved if I change package manager to npm or pnpm?
